# Usage of findViewById multiple times versus member varaible

Tags: android

I have a custom view implemented, which inflates a layout consisting of few textviews and buttons. All the views can be updated more than 2 times in one activity lifecycle. There can be 2 ways to access the view objects

1. save all the views (textviews, buttons, etc) in a member variable, access when needed
2. use findViewById, everytime the view needs to be updated

the first one is cost on memory, where as the second one is a cost on performance. Which would be a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Try the third approach [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)